# Transformation law for 1-forms on Lorentzian manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, differential-forms, vector-bundles

Let $(\mathcal{M},g)$ be a four-dimensional Lorentzian manifold and $\Sigma$ a Riemannian hypersurface such that $\mathcal{M}=\mathbb{R}\times\Sigma$ with metric of the form $g=-\alpha^{2}d t^{2}+h_{t}$ where $\alpha$ is some positive function, $t:\mathcal{M}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function and $h_{t}$ a family of Riemannian metrics on $\Sigma$.

Let $A\in\Omega^{1}(\mathcal{M})$ be a $1$-form. Clearly, I can write
$$A=A_{0}dt+A_{1}$$

where $A_{0}:=A(\partial_{t})\in C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$ and where $A_{1}:=A-A_{0}$ is a $t$-dependent $1$-form on $\Sigma$. Now, this essentially gives the isomorphism

$$\Omega^{1}(\mathcal{M})\cong C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})\oplus\Gamma(\mathrm{pr}^{\ast}T^{\ast}\Sigma)$$

where $\mathrm{pr}:\mathcal{M}\to\Sigma$ denotes the projection. (This also respects the ismorphism $T^{\ast}\mathcal{M}\cong \underline{\mathbb{R}}\oplus\mathrm{pr}^{\ast}T^{\ast}\Sigma$ obtained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4704852/restricted-cotangent-bundle)).

> **Question:** How is the information regarding the transformation law of tensors encoded in the space $C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})\oplus\Gamma(\mathrm{pr}^{\ast}T^{\ast}\Sigma)$?

For example, if $A_{0}\in C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$, then also $\partial_{t}A_{0}\in C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$.
Similarly, $\partial_{t}A_{1}\in \Gamma(\mathrm{pr}^{\ast}T^{\ast}\Sigma)$ for $A_{1}\in \Gamma(\mathrm{pr}^{\ast}T^{\ast}\Sigma)$ (since the time-derivative of a time-dependent 1-form is again a time-dependent 1-form on $\Sigma$). However, in general $\partial_{t}A\notin\Omega^{1}(\mathcal{M})$ since $\nabla_{\partial_{t}}A\neq \partial_{t}A$. Where is my thinking error?

Comment: As it stands, this isn't correct. You certainly need to assume that $dt$ is nowhere-vanishing, i.e., that $t$ is a submersion. Ordinarily $t$ is taken to be the identity on the factor $\Bbb R$. I personally would not confuse functions with $1$-forms; I would write something like  $d_t A_0 = (\partial_t A_0)dt$.

Comment: @TedShifrin indeed, there are some assumptions on $dt$. In fact, I was considering what is called a globally-hyperbolic manifold, but didn't want to be too technical when asking the question.

Comment: Anyhow, when you say "this essentially gives the isomorphism" you lose the tensorial information. You really need the free $C^\infty$-module generated by $dt$ if you want to stay tensorial.

Comment: @TedShifrin but the isomorphism is correct, or isn't it? I mean, the bundles $T^{\ast}M$ and $\underline{\mathbb{R}}\oplus \mathrm{pr}^{\ast}T^{\ast}\Sigma$ are definitely isomorphic, as shown in this other question.

Comment: Isomorphism in what category? If I say that the cotangent bundle is trivial, do you then say that the sections transform trivially (as sections of the trivial bundle do), or that they transform as covariant tensor fields (as sections of the cotangent bundle do)?

Comment: @TedShifrin Maybe, let me ask the following related question to clear my confusion: If I take an element $(\alpha,\beta)\in C^{\infty}(M)\oplus \Gamma(\mathrm{pr}^{\ast}(T^{\ast}\Sigma))$, then $\omega:=\alpha dt+\beta$ should be an element in $\Omega^{1}(M)$, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting that you need the $dt$ there if you're going to consider this as a covariant tensor field. Abstractly, it's a trivial $C^\infty$-module, but you need more information.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your answers. I am still not totally sure I understand you right. Let say I take $(\alpha,\beta)\in C^{\infty}(M)\oplus \Gamma(\mathrm{pr}^{\ast}T^{\ast}\Sigma)$. Then also $(\partial_{t}\alpha,\partial_{t}\beta)\in C^{\infty}(M)\oplus \Gamma(\mathrm{pr}^{\ast}T^{\ast}\Sigma)$. But how is $\omega:=(\partial_{t}\alpha) dt+\partial_{t}\beta$ an element in $\Omega^{1}(M)$? Does it have the right transformation law?